# Java: bug in do while loop

Tags: java, int, do-while

Please bear with me: I've only ever taken one Java class, my ideas are too big for my level of expertise but I try to implement them anyway. So my understanding of Java is flimsy, my code is convoluted.

An int in my java do-while loop is returning as 0, then after several cycles of the loop it pops up again as 10 when it shouldn't have been acted on and it shouldn't be possible for it to go up to 10.

The following is the output from a text game program

```
1. Attack
2. Block
3. Dodge
4. Escape & Evade

2
Block: 0

Damage: 4

KEELBREAKER

Physical readiness: 44/50 (FNG)


1. Attack
2. Block
3. Dodge
4. Escape & Evade

1

Attack: 6 - Block: 10 = Damage -4

MUGGER

Physical readiness: 54/50 (FNG)

Damage: 5

KEELBREAKER
Physical readiness: 25/50 (FNG)

1. Attack
2. Block
3. Dodge
4. Escape & Evade
```

See bolded. In the first cycle option 2 "block" is selected the game calculates a value of zero, no effect. Six cycles later (deleted) option 1 "attack" is selected. The game calculates a block value of 10, applies negative damage "healing" the enemy object 4 points above it's maximum health.

Obviously there's a lot wrong here. But my immediate concern is the block function. Given the input from the player and enemy objects it should not be possible to go up to ten. Furthermore, every time the player selects block it returns a value of 0. Plus, I haven't implemented the block function for the enemy object's turn so the enemy should not be able to block. So my initiating the block function returned 0 doing nothing, then the value somehow recycled through the loop 6 times doing nothing and not being displayed each time. Then magically turned into 10 for no reason, in the enemy object's turn where it shouldn't even exist. I'm very confused. This is already really long so I'm sorry about that, but now I'll attach the code. The code is... a mess. I'll try my best to clean it up as much as possible.

```
public class Combat {

public static void indivCombat(Player playerObject, Enemy enemyObject)
{
    boolean inCombat = true;
    int combatChoice = 0;
    int compResponse = 0;
    int damage = 0;
    int defense = 0;
    double evadeChance = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    int loot = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Random randNum = new Random();

    System.out.println(enemyObject.getType() + " is engaging!");

    //do while inCombat is true
    do
    {
        System.out.println("1. Attack\n2. Block\n3. Dodge\n4. Escape & Evade");
        combatChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

        //player's turn
        switch(combatChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            compResponse = (randNum.nextInt(151)+50)/100;
            if (compResponse < evadeChance)
            {
                System.out.println(enemyObject.getType() + " evaded attack!");
                damage=0;
            }
            else
            {
                damage = playerObject.getAttack() - enemyObject.getDefense() + randNum.nextInt(playerObject.getAttack() + 1);
                if (damage<0)
                    damage = 0;
                enemyObject.setHealth(enemyObject.getHealth() - damage + defense);
                if (defense != 0)
                {
                    sum = damage - defense;
                    System.out.println("Attack: "+damage + " - Block: " + defense + " = Damage " + sum);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Damage: "+damage);
                }
                enemyObject.displayEnemyHealth();
            }
            evadeChance = 0;
            defense = 0;
            break;
        case 2:             
            defense = playerObject.getDefense() - enemyObject.getAttack();
            if (defense > 0)
                defense = randNum.nextInt(playerObject.getDefense())*9/10;
            else if (defense == 0)
                compResponse = randNum.nextInt(1);
                switch (compResponse)
                {
                case 0: defense = 0;
                case 1: defense = playerObject.getDefense()*5/10;
                } 
            defense = randNum.nextInt(playerObject.getDefense())*1/10;
            System.out.println("Block: " + defense);
            break;
```

The block function is contained in case 2 at the bottom. I included everything from the beginning in case something from above is effecting it. I disincluded everything below because it's... just too long.

Now in this case playerObject.getDefense() is 4 and enemyObject.getAttack() is 5.
Regardless of how this calculated to 10. What I really don't understand is how this intially calculated as 0, then recycled through the loop 6 times even though it should terminate after the enemyObject's next attack. Then became 10 with no input on the enemyObject's turn given that it has no ability to use block?

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of info to ask someone to read and understand. Perhaps you can ask the question in programming terms in instead of a full explanation of the game?

Anyway, is it possible that this is caused by the missing brackets in the `if` in  `case 2`? The switch code will always execute, even though it's indented.